# How to make date picker dialog appear when tabbing to a date field

Tags: android, jquery, date

I have written an html5 web application and when running on Android 4.0.4, I have noticed the following issue: I have two consecutive input fields on a form, one is a text field and the next is a date field. If the focus is currently in the text field and the virtual keyboard is displayed and the "tab" button is pressed on the virtual keyboard, the focus moves to the date field, however the date picker dialog box is NOT displayed for the date field. This issue is happening in both the standard Android browser and Chrome, as follows:

Using the standard android browser, when tabbing from text to date, the keyboard stays displayed, even though the field being entered is a date field and the date picker dialog box should now be displayed.

Using Chrome, when tabbing from text to date, the keyboard disappears but the date picker dialog box is not displayed.

Either way, this is unacceptable.  When the focus moves to a date field via the tab key, the date picker dialog box should be displayed (exactly the same way that the date picker dialog box is displayed when the user touches the input type=date box).

This is without doubt yet another bug in the Android 4.0.4 OS, which I am realizing is full of such bugs. My question is this:  Is there anything programmatically I can do to work-around this to make the date picker dialog box appear when the date field is tabbed to using the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on your tabbing code

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").focus(function(){
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to use the native date picker.

If you find this is only happening when you tab over to your date inputs and not when you tap them, try listening on the focus event, blur it, remove the listener, refocus, then add the listener again.

This will probably make the interface unacceptably jerky, but there exists no DOM methods tell you what keyboard state is present or change them, beyond specifying the input type.

You'll see this kind of inconsistency is sadly the current norm: http://mir.aculo.us/2013/08/30/handling-numerical-input-in-mobile-web-apps-or-a-sad-tale-of-two-keyboards/

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use the native date picker.  I want the same picker that appears when a user taps a date field to appear if they tab to the field using virtual keyboard.  And yes, this is only happening when I tab to a date input and not when I tap the date input.

Comment: If blurring and refocusing the input doesn't fix it (or causes side effects), I'm not aware of any other method to trigger the native picker. You may want to file a bug report.